# About crankset Shimano FC-C202

Tags: crankset, chainring

Can someone please elaborate on middle ring of this vintage crankset? In four places metal looks broken, although from photos found on internet this seems to be part of design.

[image]

Roughly washed crankset from behind. "Broken" bits are on sides of middle ring.

[image]
Closeup of "broken" bit.

Comment: Welcome to the site - that's a well documented question.  Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 5):

These features are designed in to aid shifting and chain retention during shifting.

More modern or higher quality rings use riveted pins instead along with ''malformed'' teeth.